# OpenAL's AL/al.h not found on Mac OS X Lion with XCode 4.1

Tags: c++, xcode, openal

I've created a project in XCode and added the OpenAL framework. Still the compiler can't find AL/al.h when i try to include it.

Where do I add the include directory for OpenAL?

edit: Sorry I forgot to add: I'm using C/C++

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use this: `#import <OpenAL/al.h>`